# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a^3+2}\leq\frac{4}{3}$ if $a, b, c, d > 0$ and $abcd=1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be positive numbers such that $abcd=1$. Prove that:
> $$\frac{a^2}{a^3+2}+\frac{b^2}{b^3+2}+\frac{c^2}{c^3+2}+\frac{d^2}{d^3+2}\leq\frac{4}{3}.$$

Vasc's LCF Theorem does not help here. Also I tried MV method, but without success.

Comment: :I have an idea, that is to prove $F(a,b,c,d)\leqF(\sqrt{ab},\sqrt{ab},\sart{cd},\sqrt{cd}), and then prove $F(\sqrt{ab},\sqrt{ab},\sart{cd},\sqrt{cd})\leq 0$, but there are still some arguments I did not complete, if you have not tried and interested, maybe it works!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that relies on an uninspiring chain of single-variable inequalities of the form $\frac{x^2}{x^3+2}\leq \alpha+\beta\ln(x)$ on some interval for various nonnegative real $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Define $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^3+2}$. Note first that $f(x)$ is maximized when
$$f'(x)=\frac{2x(x^3+2)-3x^2(x^2)}{(x^3+2)^2}=\frac{x(4-x^3)}{(x^3+2)^2}=0,$$
i.e. when $x=2^{2/3}$, at which point $f(x)=\frac{2^{1/3}}3$. If $$\min(f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d))\leq\frac43-2^{1/3},$$
then without loss of generality let $f(a)$ be less than this bound; then
$$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d)\leq \left(\frac43-2^{1/3}\right)+\frac{2^{1/3}}3+\frac{2^{1/3}}3+\frac{2^{1/3}}3=\frac43.$$
So, we may assume that
$$f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d)\geq \frac43-2^{1/3}>0.07;$$
this implies $a,b,c,d>0.37$.

Now, define $g(x)=\frac13(1+\ln(x))$. One may check that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x>0.6$. So, if $a,b,c,d>0.6$, then
$$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d)\leq \frac43+\frac13\ln(abcd)=\frac43;$$
otherwise, without loss of generality let $a<0.6$; now $0.37<a<0.6$.

Now, define $h(x)=0.36+0.17\ln(x)$; note that $f(x)<h(x)$ for all $x>0.13$. We thus have
\begin{align*}
f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d)&\leq f(a)+1.08+0.17\ln(bcd)\\
&=1.08+\frac{a^2}{a^3+2}-0.17\ln(a). 
\end{align*}
One may verify that the one-variable function
$$j(a)=1.08+\frac{a^2}{a^3+2}-0.17\ln(a)$$
is maximized on the interval $[0.37,0.6]$ at $a=0.6$, where its value is $1.3293<\frac 43$. The inequality is thus proven.

Comment: We posted our answers almost at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

WLOG, assume that $a\ge b \ge c \ge d$.

Let
$$f(u) := \frac{u^2}{u^3 + 2}.$$

**Fact 1**: $f(u)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \sqrt[3]{4}]$
and strictly decreasing on $[\sqrt[3]{4}, \infty)$.

We split into four cases.

**Case 1**: $c > \sqrt[3]{13 - 3\sqrt{17}}$
and $a < \sqrt[3]{13 + 3\sqrt{17}}$

Let
$$g(u) := \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2u}}{\mathrm{e}^{3u} + 2}.$$
We have
$$g''(u) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2u}(\mathrm{e}^{6u} - 26\mathrm{e}^{3u} + 16)}{(\mathrm{e}^{3u}  + 2)^3}.$$
We have
$g''(u) \le 0$ on $[\ln \sqrt[3]{13 - 3\sqrt{17}}, ~ \ln \sqrt[3]{13 + 3\sqrt{17}}]$.

Thus, using Jensen's inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(a) + f(b) + f(c) &= g(\ln a) + g(\ln b) + g(\ln c)\\
 &\le 3 \, g\left(\frac{\ln a + \ln b + \ln c}{3}\right)\\
 &= 3 \cdot \frac{(abc)^{2/3}}{abc + 2}.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 3 \cdot \frac{(abc)^{2/3}}{abc + 2} + \frac{d^2}{d^3 + 2} \le \frac43
\end{align*}
or
$$3 \cdot \frac{(1/d)^{2/3}}{1/d + 2} + \frac{d^2}{d^3 + 2} \le \frac43 $$
which is true for all $d > 0$. (*Note*: Let $d = x^3$.)

**Case 2**: $d < 3/5$ and $c \le \sqrt[3]{13 - 3\sqrt {17}}$

Using Fact 1, we have
$$f(a) + f(b) + f(c) + f(d)
\le f(\sqrt[3]{4}) + f(\sqrt[3]{4})
+ f(\sqrt[3]{13 - 3\sqrt{17}}) + f(3/5) < \frac43.$$

**Case 3**: $d < 3/5$ and $a \ge \sqrt[3]{13 + 3\sqrt{17}}$

Using Fact 1, we have
$$f(a) + f(b) + f(c) + f(d)
\le f(\sqrt[3]{13 + 3\sqrt{17}}) + f(\sqrt[3]{4})
+ f(\sqrt[3]{4}) + f(3/5) < \frac43.$$

**Case 4**: $d \ge \frac35$

**Fact 2**:
$\frac{1}{3} - \frac{u^2}{u^3 + 2} + \frac13 \ln u \ge 0$ for all $u \ge 3/5$.
(*Note*: Take derivative.)

Using Fact 2, we have
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{a^2}{a^3 + 2} + \frac13 \ln a\right) \ge 0.$$
The desired result follows.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let : $a= e^{x_1}\ , \ b=e^{x_2}\ , \ c=e^{x_3} \ , \ d =e^{x_4}$

So we must to prove:

$$f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)+f(x_4) \le \dfrac{4}{3}$$

for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0 $

$$f(x)= \dfrac{e^{2x}}{e^{3x}+2}$$

Since : $f'(x)= \dfrac{e^{2x}(4-e^{3x})}{(2+e^{3x})^2}$ and $f''(x)=\dfrac{e^{2x}(e^{6x}-26e^{3x}+16)}{(2+e^{3x})^3}$

We only need to consider the inequality in case : $x_1=x_2=x_3=t\ , \ x_4= -4t$

$\Leftrightarrow a=b=c=x \ ,\ d=\dfrac{1}{x^3}$

$g(x)=\dfrac{3x^2}{x^3+2}+\dfrac{x^3}{1+2x^9} \ , x>0$

$g'(x)=\dfrac{3x(1-x^4)(4x^{17}-16x^{14}+4x^{13}+4x^{12}-16x^{10}+20x^9+8x^8+4x^5+8x^4-x^3+4x+4)}{(x^3+2)^2(2x^9+1)^2}$

Maximum is attained at $x=1\ ,\ g(1)=\dfrac{4}{3}$

Equality holdes for : $(a=b=c=d=1)$

Comment: No! The Vasc's theorems don't help here.

Comment: it is not Vasc.

Comment: If so, explain please why we can assume $a=b=c$?

Answer (score -3):

### Partial answer with Computer

As $a,b,c\in[0,1]$ we use for $x\in[0,1]$:

$$x/3\geq x^2/(x^3+2)\tag{I}$$

Using $I$ three times we need to show :

$$t(a,b,c)=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{\left(abc\right)^{-2}}{\left(abc\right)^{-3}+2}\leq4/3$$

Now we expand to get ($p,q,r\geq 0$) :

$$t(1/(p+1),1/(q+1),1/(r+1))-4/3\leq 0$$

All the coefficients are negatives . We can also use $abc's$ method .

---

---

We have a first inequality for $x\in[0,1]$:

$$\frac{x^{2}}{x^{3}+2}-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x\left(1-x\right)^{2}}{3}\leq 0$$

As we have $a,b\in[0,1]$  assume $b\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}}}< a\leq 1= c<4^{1/3}\leq d$ using $I$ we have the two inequalities :

$$f(a,b)=\frac{a\left(1-a\left(b-1\right)\right)+\left(1+2\left(1-a\right)\left(\left|a-b\right|\right)\right)b}{6}+\frac{c^{2}}{c^{3}+2}-\frac{b\left(b-1\right)^{2}\left(1-a\right)}{3}-\frac{a\left(a-1\right)^{2}}{6}-\frac{2}{3}\leq 0\tag{G}$$

And :

$$\frac{a\left(1+a\left(b-1\right)\right)+b\left(1-2\left(1-a\right)\left(\left|a-b\right|\right)\right)}{6}+\frac{d^{2}}{d^{3}+2}-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{b\left(b-1\right)^{2}a}{3}-\frac{a\left(a-1\right)^{2}}{6}\leq 0\tag{g}$$

For the first we have $G$

$$f\left(\frac{x}{x+y},\frac{\frac{793701}{1000000}y}{x+y}\right)=-y (1500000000000000000x³ + 3706299000000000000x² y + 2973188222599000000x y² + 1266890118433451101y³) / (3000000000000000000(x + y)⁴)$$

For the second $g$ use the same substitution all the coefficients are negatives

We can also choose instead of $793701/1000000$ a less but positive value .

Summing yields the inequality in this case .

---

---

Hint for the last case $a\in[0,1]$ and $b,c,d\in[1,\infty]$:

We have the inequality for $x\in[0,2]$ :

$$\frac{x^{2}}{x^{3}+2}\leq h(x)=\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{\frac{7}{2}+x^{2}} $$

Or :

$$\frac{x\left(x-2\right)\left(x-1\right)^{2}\left(2x+1\right)^{2}}{3\left(2x^{2}+7\right)\left(x^{3}+2\right)}\leq 0$$

Now we have for $x\geq 0$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}\left(h\left(e^{x}\right)\right)=-(e^{x}(-2352e^{x}+1848e^{2x}+672e^{3x}+108e^{4x}+16e^{6x}-49))/(3(2e^{2x}+7)^{3})$$

So it's clearly negatives so the function is concave .

As in RiverLi's answer we can use Jensen's inequality and show the inequality :

$$\frac{4}{3}\ge\frac{x^{2}}{x^{3}+2}+3h\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$ for $x\in[0,0.2]$ or $x\in[0.45,1]$

I stop here because the rest is smooth .

Comment: You may write a complete detailed proof. During 3 years, I never see your complete detailed proof. You can look into some proofs for inequalities in this site. For example,""WLOG, assume that $a \le b \le c \le d$", "We split into four cases. Case 1, blablabla, Case 2, blablabla ...".

Comment: We can make the same reasoning at the end with $$h\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{3}-\frac{0.75x\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{\frac{5}{3}+x^{2}}$$ for $x\in[1,2]$

Comment: You should write a complete detailed proof (format). Not just hint, remark, the rest is smooth.